# invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character' -- in self-defined function with lattice histogram

Tags: r, error-handling, lattice

I want a function with parameters such as data name (dat), factor(myfactor), variable names(myvar) to dynamically generate histograms (have to use lattice).

Using IRIS as a minimal example:

```
data(iris)



my_histogram <- function(myvar,myfactor,dat){
    listofparam <- c(myvar,myfactor)
    myf <- as.formula(paste("~",paste(listofparam,collapse="|")))
    histogram(myf,
              data=dat,
              main=bquote(paste(.(myvar),"distribution by",.(myfactor),seq=" ")))}



my_histogram("Sepal.Length","Species","iris")
```

I also tried do.call as some posts indicated:

```
my_histogram <- function(myvar,myfactor,dat){
listofparam <- c(myvar,myfactor)
myf <- as.formula(paste("~",paste(listofparam,collapse="|")))
p <- do.call("histogram",
   args = list(myf,
   data=dat))
print(p)

}

my_histogram("Sepal.Length","Species","iris")
```

But the error appears: `invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'. I think the program doesn't know where to look for this`myf` string. How can I fix this or there's a better way?

Comment: Don't need do.call here. Without sending the data object's name as a character but sending the data object itself,  you could just use: `histogram(myf,  data=dat)`

Comment: I have now effectively answered two different questions about two different errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readers of this should be aware that the question has completely mutated from an earlier version and doesn't really match up with this answer anymore. The answer to the new question appears in the comments.

There is no object named `Sepal.Length`. (So R is creating an error even before that `my_function` gets called.) There is only a column name and it would need to be quoted to pass it to a function. (The data object could not be created because that URL fails to deliver the data. Why aren't you using the built-in copy of the iris data object?

You will also need to build a formula from `myvar` and `fac`. Formulas are expressions and get parsed without evaluation of their tokens. You need to build a formula inside your function that looks like: `~Sepal.Length|Species` and then pass it to the histogram call.  Consult `?as.formula`

Comment: Hi @DWin, thanks for your reply. I re-wrote the program based on your suggestion, but there's a new error on the environment. I wonder if you know how to fix it? I appreciate your help!

Comment: I think I found something about do.call. Will try that first!

Comment: Your code works if you do not put quotes around "iris". That was why you were getting this error:"Error in eval(substitute(groups), data, environment(formula)) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'"

Comment: Thank you! This really works. So, why column names have to be quoted, but data doesn't have to? I'm quite new to R and sorry if the question sounds too basic.

Comment: Columns are not objects (at least at the Global environment level). Functions that use a formula interface create a new environment where the tokens in the formula get "looked up" in the 'data'-object environment. You could pass an expression instead of a character vector, but I think you may not want to dive into that part of computing on the language just yet.

Comment: Will take notes about this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @DWin, speaking about formula, is "dataname$value1" a formula too? If not, in such case, can I use paste(dataname,"$",value1) to pass the value to a function?

Comment: I would not see dataname$value1 as a formula. Typically one would put a tilde as the leading text item if one wanted to use a single token in a formula. If you wanted to build an expression you would start with `paste()`-ing text and then wrap it in `as.formula(...)`.